# how to find string in sentence using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying find word in the sentence, what i should do in order to find string in the sentence instead of each character of the string in sentence?

Note: i'm trying to achieve this using for loop.  I don't want to use split() or in-build functions.

```
def word_in_sen(sentence, word):
result = ''
for i in word:
    for j in sentence:
        if i == j:
            result += i
            break
if result == word:
    return True

else:
    return False
```

print(word_in_sen("Welcome to python programming ", "python"))
print(word_in_sen("Welcome to python programming ", "long"))

'''
Scenario: 1

checking whether the word "Python" available in the big string.

Expected result: True

Actual result: True

'''

'''
Scenario: 1

checking whether the word "long" available in the big string.

Expected result: False

Actual result: True

'''

Comment: Split the string into words, then use `if word in words`

Comment: This is built in functionality in python. Don't make your own function.

Comment: You're approach will not work... you're looping over each substring. Just use the `in` operator